# State view and application view asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, viewstate

Can you give some links whit, code examples, what is State view and application view for beginners to better understand ?

Comment: Did you check the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_viewstate.asp

http://asp.net-tutorials.com/state/viewstate/